# How to add some event to twig in symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I want add my control code before rendering template.

Example:
Have templates:
  user.html.twig

Controller:

```
return $this->render('....:user.html.twig', array(/* variables */))
```

I want add other variables before rendering template.

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you make it clearer?

Comment: I want add other variables before rendering template. For example: Automatic add to all templates my service variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution this problem:

Create a new Twig extension and register this extension.

Example:

Twig extension:

```
class UserExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
  /**
   * Get globals variables
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function getGlobals()
  {
    return array(
      // Other variables
    );
  }
}
```

Register extension as service.

```
<service id="sps.twig.user_extension" class="SPS\Bundles\HomeBundle\Twig\Extensions\UserExtension">
  <tag name="twig.extension" />
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::render` method in your controller and pass additional variables or arrange some events hooks there or in Twig.

Comment: This is bad idea (( If using this solution, than i must each controller extends at base me controller